# Consumer API - Cards

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

I have completed the [Build Your First Plugin](https://banno.github.io/open-api-docs/plugins/quickstarts/buildyourfirstplugin) tutorial and that’s all working fine.  I have retrieved my account using the Consumer API with the Node.js Express app and from the command line with curl.

The Accounts API seems rather straightforward.  Now I’m trying to determine how I go about retrieving the debit cards associated with my account?

I’m looking at the OpenAPI / Swagger stuff, but I’m not sure how to get Cards API to work exactly.

[Accounts](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/consumer-api/api-reference/v0/accounts/details) - From the Accounts API doc, I copied this userId, 01234567-abcd-4321-fedc-9876543210fa, to use in the Cards API.

[Cards](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/consumer-api/api-reference/v0/cards/)

> The Cards API is used to perform actions related to credit/debit
> cards.

As you can see in this screenshot, I pasted the userId that I copied from the Accounts API doc.

[Cards API screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRpFN.png) - The response was a 401:

> “Failed to determine Banno auth type”

I suspect this has something to do with selecting the proper OpenID scopes?

I clicked the lock icon next to the Basic Cards API Get button.  I selected the two OpenID scopes that it showed as being required?

[CardControls-ReadOnly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C733U.png)

[CardControls-ReadWrite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmAiE.png)

When I click the Authorize button it redirects to the digital.garden-fi.com site, but I don’t recall seeing a user name and password that I can use to test.

I obviously didn’t want to put my personal information into this site just to create an account to test with.

[Garden test site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8lB2.png)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different things to unpack in your question, so I'll do my best to separate things out.

### 1) To use the Consumer API's Cards endpoints, you'll definitely need to use the correct OAuth scopes when beginning the authentication flow.

For example, for the *GET ​/users​/{userId}​/cards* endpoint, you'll need to use either the https://api.banno.com/consumer/auth/cardcontrols.readonly or https://api.banno.com/consumer/auth/cardcontrols.readwrite scope. You only need one of them, not both.

This is what you would need to use as a curl command in the Terminal, for example:

```
curl -X 'GET' \
'https://[CONSUMER_API_ENVIRONMENT]/a/consumer/api/v0/users/{userId}/cards' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]'
```

...where:

- `CONSUMER_API_ENVIRONMENT` is specific to your financial institution and matches with Banno Online for your institution
- `userId` is the ID for the User.
- `YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN` is your Access Token from the authentication flow (in JWT format)

Notably, you will need to user the `userId` for *your* user. Your question mentioned using `01234567-abcd-4321-fedc-9876543210fa`, but from what I see that's not the ID of an actual user but is instead an *example* of how such an ID would be formatted. Apologies for the confusion.

### 2) The 'Interactive' API Reference

The 'interactive' API Reference that you're using is meant to be used with a demo financial institution that we have named *Garden* (https://www.garden-fi.com).

From what I can tell in your description, it sounds like you don't have a user nor API credentials for the *Garden* demo institution. Which is okay, because it's actually preferable for you to use a user and API credentials within your own financial institution.

Based on the fact that you've already gone through the *Build Your First Plugin* quickstart, it sounds like you've *already* got your own user and API credentials set up in your financial institution's Banno environment (which is actually ideal for what you're trying to do).

Again, apologies for the confusion.

Comment: Yup I was lost in the Garden :)  Used it to rule out possible issues with our env.

Following the Accts & Txns guide I can see my account.  I understand that is because the accounts.readonly scope was included.

To see txns I need the transactions.readonly scope?  RFC 6749 section 3.3: "The value of the scope parameter is expressed as a list of space-delimited, case-sensitive strings."

So sounds like I just need to add this:  encodeURIComponent('https://api.banno.com/consumer/auth/transactions.readonly')

The curl command returns: "user not permitted to access resource"

Comment: For anybody that might be reading this in the future, Jaime was very helpful here and on the Banno Digital Toolkit Office Hours call.    

The correct scope for Transactions is
`https://api.banno.com/consumer/auth/transactions.detail.readonly`  

Refer to the [Transaction Details API doc](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/consumer-api/api-reference/v0/transactions/details/#/Transactions%20list/get_users__userId__accounts__accountId__transactions)

Comment: Back to the Cards API.  The curl cmd is working now that I have included the proper scope: `https://api.banno.com/consumer/auth/cardcontrols.readonly`, but now the command is returning `{"data":[]}`.  

Basic Card Functionality - Get method from the [Cards Details API doc](https://banno.github.io/open-api-docs/consumer-api/api-reference/v0/cards/details/#/Basic%20Cards/get_users__userId__cards) says:  

>Returns (OnDot and Passport) debit and (OnDot only) credit cards.  

Do you have to get your cards via Jack Henry for this to work?  We get ours from Transfund. Any idea @Jaime

Comment: For both banks and credit unions, retrieving debit card info via the API requires the institution to have the Basic Card Controls feature in Banno. For credit card, I believe it requires having JHA Full Service Credit contracted and installed for Banno.

Comment: It's my understanding that some portion of this would require contracts to be in place to enable the feature in Banno, but that's not my area of expertise. I would suggest speaking with your account representative for more info on getting this set up in Banno.